# Bypass profile attribute character limit in Enterprise 2.0

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send

We had previously implemented a TriggeredSend setup that bypasses the 4000 character limit on the profile attributes by following instructions outlined in the following links.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000220898&language=en_US
[ExactTarget TriggeredSend - Replace variable HTML__BODY?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73217/exacttarget-triggeredsend-replace-variable-html-body)

However when recently trying to set up a similar configuration in an Enterprise 2.0 account we discovered that you no longer had the option of not setting a limit. As you can see from the screenshot below, we no longer have the ability the ability to bypass the 4K character limit.

[image]

This seems to be a recent limitation that was introduced in Enterprise 2.0 accounts. I am wondering if anyone is aware of any workarounds to this restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a recent limitation added to profile attributes for ENT2.0 accounts.  Try using a Data Extension instead of a list to store your Triggered Send information, and use "HTML__" for the field to bypass the max field length limit of 4000.  Data Extensions will always give you more flexibility and performance than the All Subscribers model.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the `HTML__` solution? I'm curious to learn this one. Are you prefixing DE fields with this string? I simply delete the string length in the DE field (so it's blank) which let's me store an almost unlimited amount of data (up to ~8MB in size), but I'd be keen to find out more about your approach.

Comment: Sure, this is a special field for Data Extensions which are designed to store HTML.  You would prefix the field name with HTML__ and add something identifiable after such as "HTML__Body".  This might be more efficient than deleting the string length field in the Data Extension, although I'm not sure how much more.  Perhaps its the same as removing the field length amount.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000220898&language=en_US

Comment: @CCarswell Can you elaborate how to use data extension in Email Template? I cannot find the way. It is complaining about lack of attributes defined in profile management

Comment: @Marcin If you are using Send Preview/Sending to a Data Extension that contains the field you want to use in the email (say, %%BirthDate%%) then it shouldn't complain about the missing profile attributes.  If you are Send Preview/Sending to a list and you are missing the %%BirthDate%% profile attribute then it would give an error.  Also, when using Validate, make sure to validate against the Data Extension that you are sending to to prevent errors.

Comment: @CCarswell Sorry, about confusion, but I'm trying to use triggered send. And I cannot publish (save) because email is no fields. I'm new with salesforce api, and cannot find documentation how to setup all together. To send whole email from external app.